# Magento 2 upgrade from 2.0.10 to 2.1.2 - broken pages style on User Account Information/Dashboard

Tags: magento2, upgrade

did anyone experience this issue after upgrading from magento 2 2.0.10 to 2.1.2?

after the upgrade, it breaks the display of the page. It sends the page top heading to the very bottom of the page. In this case, the heading "My Orders" ends up at the bottom of the page.

Is there anyway to fix this?

Thanks.

[image]